# Cannot find module '../build/Release/node_expat.node'

Tags: node.js

I am trying to read file xls file in NODE JS my sample code is as below

```
var fs = require('fs');
var htmlparser = require("htmlparser");
var office = require('office');

exports.onlyText = function(test) {
test.expect(3);
var handler = new htmlparser.DefaultHandler(function (error, dom) {
    test.ok(!error, error); 
var text =  htmlparser.DomUtils.getElementsByTagName("P",     dom)[0].children[0].raw;
    test.strictEqual(text, '213', 'text data');
    test.done();
});
office.parse(__dirname + '/test.xls', function(err, data) {
    test.ok(!err, err);
    var parser = new htmlparser.Parser(handler);
    parser.parseComplete(data);
});
};
```

I don't know where i am wrong

Answer (score 1):

That error is originating from one of your node modules (probably [node-expat](https://github.com/astro/node-expat)). Make sure npm was able to properly install all the modules.